# Pandas: How to create a datetime dataframe index from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the below to create a dataframe using Pandas on Python 2.7.  How to I get utcdt to be the time series index?

```
data_hash = {u'impressions': 105.0, u'campaign_id': u'cid2504649263', 'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 29, 18, 0)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_hash, orient="index")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transpose the dataframe first before setting the index:

```
df.T.set_index('utcdt')
Out[133]: 
                    impressions    campaign_id
utcdt                                         
2013-10-29 18:00:00         105  cid2504649263
```